# Xamarin forms UWP AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed doesn't seem to work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm using Xamarin Forms 3.6.
I want to hide the back button in the UWP app.
In the UWP App.xaml.cs OnLaunced I've added.

```cs
SystemNavigationManager
     .GetForCurrentView()
     .AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
```

I've also added it to each ContentPage (using dependency injection) so that in the constructor of each page runs the above code.

Each content page, I've also added:

```cs
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

I always still seem to get the back button in the title bar on UWP.
Any ideas in Xamarin Forms UWP how to hide and keep hidden the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, please invoke `SetHasBackButton` static method in the page where you want to hide back button like the following.

```
public ItemDetailPage(ItemDetailViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
    BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
}
```